# How to release browser memory on infinite scrolling load more data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, yii

As infinite scrolling provides best user experience I have implemented it. But now the problem I have found is *Freezing Browser on Load more*.

Firstly, I have implemented lazy loading and masonry grid for making a view like pintrest.com But the issue is When a user clicks on load more button to load more contents the browser is freezing and unable to scroll smoothly. I have set `cache: false` in the load more `ajax` call.

Is there any method so that I can release the memory of browser on load more button click? just like an Angular JS

Please provide the best solution.

Comment: try to compress all your files with gzip

Comment: Yes, I already enabled it from cpanel. But no luck

Comment: I think there is no way to do it